# Javascript concatenating numbers, not adding up

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile

It keeps concatenating my numbers into 2111 instead of 5. Why is this? I've tried using parseInt with no luck. res3 btw represents a query into my database that I'm executing.

```
var dt_total_hours = 0;

            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_cost_per_hour);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_prod_dt_hours);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_prod_rate);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_cost_per_unit);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_scrap_startup_cost);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_labor_expense);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_since_issues_first_noticed);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_wo_for_maint);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_investigation);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_maint_made_bandaid);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_parts_outsourcing);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_get_equip_out_prod);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_perm_repair);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_equip_back_to_prod);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_to_full_prod_speed);
            dt_total_hours += res3.fieldByName(dt_other);
```

Comment: You have strings, not numbers.

Comment: You can cast strings to numbers using a `+`, though, so `dt_total_hours += +'1'` will add `1`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks Paul and Maerics..it was a combination of the Number method with the single quotes. Very helpful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the values are strings then they will be concatenated, not added numerically.

Try [constructing a number from the string value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

```javascript
dt_total_hours += Number(res3.fieldByName(dt_cost_per_hour));
//                ^------ Force a number here instead of a string.
```

Comment: dt_total_hours += Number(res3.fieldByName(dt_cost_per_hour));

Comment: @wowzuzz: note that if the string cannot be parsed into a number then it will return `NaN` which will cause the sum to be `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's reading them as strings. I find that a dirty, awful hack to get them interpreted as numbers is to take `x += y` and change it to `x += y / 1.0` (or `/ 1` for integer). Usually does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

you can parse your data according to desired type as follow

```
dt_total_hours += parseInt(res3.fieldByName(dt_cost_per_hour));
```

you can also use parseFloat method as well