# Trying to add three numbers in javascript using functions but its not adding them instead it just writes them as one number

Tags: javascript, function, addition

Trying to add three numbers in javascript using functions but its not adding them instead it just writes them as one number

```
function numinput(a,b,c,res){
a = prompt("Enter first number");
    b = prompt("Enter second number");
    c =  prompt("Enter third number");

    res = a + b + c ;
    alert (res);
}  

numinput();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript concatenating numbers, not adding up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656003/javascript-concatenating-numbers-not-adding-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the values to numbers using

> parseInt

. Here's a working solution.

```js
function numinput(a,b,c,res){
        a = parseInt(prompt("Enter first number"), 10);
        b = parseInt(prompt("Enter second number"), 10);
        c = parseInt(prompt("Enter third number"), 10);

        res = a + b + c ;
        alert (res);
    }

    numinput();
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Although you could use the unary operator + in front of each variable, parseInt(var, radix) is more explicit when it comes to human legibility.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Yup having the + will do the job through coercion, but thanks for the input mate!

Answer (score 1):

[prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns a `string`. You need to first convert the string to number otherwise you are concatenating strings: `'5' + '7' === '57'`

Here are some ways to achieve this:

**1 -** Using [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```
Number('5');
```

**2 -** Using [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
parseInt('20', 10);
parseFloat('5.5');
```

**3 -** Unary `+` operator as other answers explained

```
+'5'
```

**Working demo:**

```js
function numinput() {
    var a = prompt("Enter first number"),
        b = prompt("Enter second number"),
        c = prompt("Enter third number"),
        res = Number(a) + Number(b) + Number(c);
      
    alert(res);
}

numinput();
```

Answer (score 0):

The each user entry is `typeof string`, it's being concatenated into one whole `string`. If you want to add every element as a `Math` operation, parse the entries into numbers, using `+` sign in front of variables or parse it using `parseInt` function.

```js
function numinput(a, b, c, res) {
  a = prompt("Enter first number");
  b = prompt("Enter second number");
  c = prompt("Enter third number");

  res = +a + +b + +c;
  alert(res);
}

numinput();
```

Comment: up for unary + operator. I dont see many people using it these days. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert every value, which is a string, to a number with an unary `+`.

Then I suggest to move the variables declaration into the function and not inside of the parameters of the function, because you do not need them in this way and you assign the values inside of the function.

```js
function numinput() {
    var a = +prompt("Enter first number"),
        b = +prompt("Enter second number"),
        c = +prompt("Enter third number"),
        res = a + b + c;
      
    alert(res);
}

numinput();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const add = function(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

const result = add(4,5,6);
console.log(result);
```